# Exclude the three first items of a sorted list

Tags: ansible

How can I print a sorted list excluding its three first items?
Below is my Ansible playbook:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    filesDel: "{{ filesDel|default({})|
                  combine({item.NameOfFile: findFiles.files|
                  sort(attribute='mtime', reverse = true)|
                  map(attribute='path')|
                  select('search', item.NameOfFile)|
                  list}) }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ fileList }}"
```

---

I tried this, but it is not working

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.value[0:-3] }}"
  with_dict:
    - "{{ filesDel }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

When I removed [0:-3], I do get the whole list of data grouped by file name, for instance:

```
 ok: [142.20.10.15] => (item=fileName.png) => {
    "msg": [
        "/filePathA/fileName.png.25751.2020-08-31@19:30:59~",
        "/filePathB/fileName.png.25752.2020-08-31@19:30:59~", 
        "/filePathB/fileName.png.25751.2020-08-30@22:30:59~",
        "/filePathB/fileName.png.2222.2020-08-31@19:30:59~",
        "/filePathB/fileName.png.2222.2020-08-31@19:30:59~", 
        "/filePathA/fileName.png.2222.2020-08-30@22:30:59~"
    ]
}
```

When I add `[0:-3]`, I get:

```
ok: [142.20.10.15] => (item=fileName.png) => {
    "msg": [
        "/filePathA/fileName.png.25751.2020-08-31@19:30:59~",
        "/filePathB/fileName.png.25752.2020-08-31@19:30:59~", 
        "/filePathB/fileName.png.25751.2020-08-30@22:30:59~"
    ]
}
```

This not correct as those files are the first 3 files.
What I want is to **exclude** those 3 files, so, I should get:

```
 ok: [142.20.10.15] => (item=fileName.png) => {
    "msg": [
        "/filePathB/fileName.png.2222.2020-08-31@19:30:59~",
        "/filePathB/fileName.png.2222.2020-08-31@19:30:59~", 
        "/filePathA/fileName.png.2222.2020-08-30@22:30:59~"
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

Basically, the files are sorted based on the time they were created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slicing syntax of Python that you can use in Ansible works like this:

> ```
> [start:end:step]
> ```

<sup>*For reference, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice*</sup>

In this syntax, if you use a negative value, the reference is not the beginning of the list but the end.
Still, in this syntax, any element can be left empty, where `[:]` would actually means from the beginning to the end of the list.

So your actual trial `[0:-3]` means that you want

- the items from the first element of the list (`start: 0`)
- until the end - 3 of the list (`end: -3`)

---

If you want all the element except the three first then, you need

- the items from the third element of the list (`start: 3`)
- until the end of the list (`end:`  – so it stays empty)

So your correct slice notation is `[3:]`.

Given the task:

```yaml
- debug: 
    msg: "{{ filesDel[3:] }}"
  vars:
    filesDel:
      - "/filePathA/fileName.png.25751.2020-08-31@19:30:59~"
      - "/filePathB/fileName.png.25752.2020-08-31@19:30:59~" 
      - "/filePathB/fileName.png.25751.2020-08-30@22:30:59~"
      - "/filePathB/fileName.png.2222.2020-08-31@19:30:59~"
      - "/filePathB/fileName.png.2222.2020-08-31@19:30:59~" 
      - "/filePathA/fileName.png.2222.2020-08-30@22:30:59~"
```

This yields the list:

```
- /filePathB/fileName.png.2222.2020-08-31@19:30:59~
- /filePathB/fileName.png.2222.2020-08-31@19:30:59~
- /filePathA/fileName.png.2222.2020-08-30@22:30:59~
```

Comment: I tired this as well previously. It was working. However, if we have 7 items, It still show 3 bottom lines. I expecting to display 4. If have 5 records, it is showing bottom 3. leaving the top 2. I want it keep 3 reocrd, and list down the rest. The reason is that, later i will use this path to delete the files

Comment: Then you should edit your question and add the list of files and desired output for 7 files. From your explanation alone it is not totally clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: hi, sorry ya if my question was confused. The list of files is not fixed. It is dynamic whereby it will keep on increasing. Is there a solution for this. Is there any option like > than to be added

Comment: I know your files are not hardcoded... And having files > 3 is possible using `[3:]`. Edit your question to add an example of your files and expected result with more than 6 files if this does not answer your question.